# New CiviMail does not use the 'CMS editor' set in 'Display settings'

Tags: civimail, joomla, wysiwyg

We recently upgraded to 4.6.2 but CiviMail does not present the Joomla Default WYSIWYG editor like it did in previous versions but only displays the CKEditor.

We are using JCE editor and it's ability to more easily upload and manage images worked well.

Also, the CKEditor is throwing a 404 error when I try to 'Browse Server' for an image, (Send it to the server doesn't work either).

This all means that it is a bit difficult for users to add images to mailings.

Is there any way of getting the new civimail to use the default CMS WYSYWIG like before?

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the new CiviMail approach necessitated disabling the "use CMS default" option for WYSIWYG.  The new preferred approach is CiviCRM extensions to implement other WYSIWYG editors - it took about an hour to create the first WYSIWYG extension for CiviCRM, and others can build even quicker, using that extension as a guide.  You can find it here: https://github.com/relldoesphp/com.aghstrategies.tinymce

Comment: Great, thanks for the info, could you shed any light on why the 'Browse Server' or upload features within the default editor isn't working?

Comment: If I saw the URL that was causing the 404 error I'd have more of a clue - but I would check **Administer menu > System Settings > Directories** (the first three settings) and **Administer menu > System Settings > Resource URLs (the Image Upload URL).  Confirm that these settings are a) all set, b) the corresponding directories exist on the server, and c) their permissions are correctly set (the web server user should be able to read/write)

Comment: WYSIWYG Editor setting is defunct? Can't change to even no editor. CKeditor is now appending to <img> tag "src=" class to "dfsrc=".

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Tim Otten's patch that will be released with 4.6.3 fixes this problem, at least, it did for me.