# WYSIWYG editor missing from Scheduled Reminders popup window in Civi 4.6.3

Tags: joomla, scheduled-reminders, wysiwyg, 4.6.3

I recently upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6.3 from 4.4.XX. Since then, the WYSIWYG editor is missing when creating a new scheduled reminder or editing an existing one. To reproduce the error:
1. Click Manage Events
2. Click Configure an event, and choose Schedule Reminders.
3. Edit or create a new reminder
4. See the editor missing.

However if on step 2, you instead choose Info and Settings, then click Schedule Reminders, the WYSIWYG editor does appear.

I've verified the error with IE, FF and Chrome, and I see the issue 100% of the time. Using Joomla 2.5.28.

Anybody else see this issue?

Comment: Did you verify it on the demo site as well?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2122/new-civimail-does-not-use-the-cms-editor-set-in-display-settings.  @Mark Schultz, please confirm?

Comment: It works OK on the demo site.  I'm using Joomla 2.5, not 3.

It's not exactly the same issue as http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2122/new-civimail-does-not-use-the-cms-editor-set-in-display-settings

I do see the editor in info and settings windows, not in schedule reminders popups though.

Comment: Jon, can you give me a clue how to install this new TinyMCE editor? thanks.
https://github.com/relldoesphp/com.aghstrategies.tinymce

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question of how to install the TinyMCE editor extension:  It's marked as compatible with CiviCRM 4.7+.  I'm guessing it relies on functionality that doesn't exist in the current version of CiviCRM - but you could always e-mail Tyrell directly and ask him.

Assuming it works - it's submitted to the CiviCRM extensions directory, but hasn't been approved yet.  So first, make sure you have your extensions directory and URL defined (one is in **Administer menu > System Settings > Directories**, the other in **Administer menu > System Settings > Resource URLs**).  Then place the extension in a folder inside the extensions directory (use FTP or git or whatever works for you).  At this point, you should be able to go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Manage Extensions** and select "Install" for the extension.  If it works on 4.6, report back here please!

Answer (score 1):

This is working correctly on the demo site, so may be a bug on your website. You may wish to check the [CiviCRM javascript troubleshooting guide](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850.0.html), and also try disabling plugins/extensions.

The TinyMCE editor extension is only for CiviCRM 4.7+ so is not applicable to your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I will wait for 4.7 before trying the extension.